# How to use tabula to retrieve a clean table from PDF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabula

I am trying to parse my bank statements in PDF format. I tried to use `tabula.convert_into()` to first extract the table from the PDF as csv file for my further processing. There are multiple pages in the PDF file and I intend to combine them into 1 single table.

```
import tabula
    tabula.convert_into(sourceFile, endFile.csv,output_format="csv",pages="all",java_options="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8")
```

However, the CSV file retrieved is very dirty:
[image: CSV file retrieved (actual amount masked)]
From where one can see the different "Balance" number (underlined in red) is not in same column, and different "Deposit" number (highlighted in yellow) is not in same column.

They are retrieved from different pages from the PDF file, while looks clean to me, as both "Balance" and "Deposit" numbers are aligned across different pages, with no misalignment:

[image: Previous page, for first half of the table]

[image: Second page, for second half of the table]

Is there anyway where I could retrieve a clean table from the PDF using tabula?
I am very new to python so appreciate your help!

[image: Example of clean Table, desired target]

Comment: maybe get every page as separated csv, next use Python/Pandas to correct every csv (move data to correct column), and finally join all to one csv.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the comment. I have tried and it seems I will have to write a different code to clean each csv file (for each page), as each table is not clean in their own way without pattern. (e.g the first Deposit amount x.x is in adjacent column with no header, I need to move it 1 column left; but in other tables Deposit amount might be 2 columns apart where I need to move 2 column left).  I have many files of many pages, so I'm still hoping to be able to retrieve a clean table from the start, given my original PDF should be contain one, by the looks of it.

Comment: I think you could automate it - you would have to get every page separatelly but later you can check column by column and if column is empty (there is no header) then remove column. If you still get empy column then remove it again this column. This way `Deposit` should move to correct column.